# Unable to filter by regex the ouput of bind -p

Tags: bash, cygwin

I tried to do filter from the output of `bind -p` bash command. I tried this command:

```
bind -p | grep '.*forward.*'
```

The output was:

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

What's the problem? Maybe it depends on the terminal (I'm using the latest cygwin).

Comment: Works fine for me in under *nix. Hint: you can omit the `.*` and get the same result.

Comment: Quite possibly the output has DOS line endings on Cygwin, causing `grep` to incorrectly think it's binary data. Try `bind -p | tr -d '\015' | grep forward`

Comment: I can confirm the problem with cygwin, but there are no `\r` in the output of `bind -p`. There are a couple of special characters in the middle, but none that should trigger grep's heuristic (which checks for null bytes). Odd.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have cygwin to test, but you can force `grep` to treat its input as-if it was text. The flag is `-a`:

> Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the `--binary-files=text` option.

So try:

```
bind -p | grep -a forward
```